# I would like to ask: the setting of the reward function in the reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I would like to ask: when the reward function is composed of different optimization objectives, assuming that the dimensions of these objectives are inconsistent, do you need to dimensionalize these objectives. Many thanks for you! Allow me to introduce an example first. In the paper (doi.org/10.1016/j.trc.2021.103489), the reward in Eq.(17) is compiled like this: r=w1×R1+w2×R2+w3×R3+w4×R4:
[image]
where the r1 denotes the driving speed (m/s) while the r3 is the fuel consumption (kw/ton). Thus the two components have different dimensions. How can they be combined directly?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated, we're happy to have you! Unfortunately, I suspect you'll have difficulty getting a good answer to this question as it is. Can you do a little bit more exposition, and help us understand exactly what you mean by a reward function being composed of different objectives, and what the dimension of an objective is?

Comment: Thanks for your kind response! Allow me to introduce an example first. In the paper (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.trc.2021.103489), the reward in Eq.(17) is compiled like this: r=w1×R1+w2×R2+w3×R3+w4×R4, where the r1 denotes the driving speed (m/s) while the r3 is the fuel consumption (kw/ton). Thus the two components have different dimensions. How can they be combined directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reward is a unitless quantity you want to maximize. So if $R_v$ is in units of $m/s$, then $w_2$ is in units of $s/m$. (Alternatively, if you prefer, the reward is in units of "utilons" and $w_2$ is in utilon seconds / meter).

Comment: Thanks very much! I got it!